# Firefox goes slowly after i installed ubuntu update

Tags: updates, firefox, browser

I'm A Ubuntu 13.04 User , Everything Was good but software updater told me that there are new updates so I'm Installed All of the Updates (including Firefox) but after this update ,my Firefox goes so slowly & Hangs up in seconds ! Can I down date!(opposite of update!) My Firefox ? if OK How ? I have a Nightly (A 64-bit Beta version of Firefox) in Windows 7, I'm using that for a long time & I Think That was & is GREAT ,Can I install Nightly in Ubuntu 13.04 ? Again if OK How ? (sorry for my bad English)Thanks!

- for karel's question I have : Core i5 cpu , 4Gb Ram , 2Gb VGA
  (NVIDIA)

Comment: Of course you can "down date" Firefox or "Force Version" as it is called in Synaptic if that is what you really want to do, but if your hardware permits it you can also speed up Firefox by enabling hardware graphic acceleration and increasing the amount of RAM memory in your browser cache. It's up to you. If you want to learn more, then add information about the amount of RAM you have and your graphics card, if you have one, to your question.

Comment: I would never recommend downgrading your installation of Firefox, for the simple reason that each new version carries with it various security updates. Just as you would be ill-advised to revert to a previous version of a virus scanner, I would say you'd be ill-advised to revert to a previous version of a browser.

Comment: Why don't you make a [second profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)? If that is fine, it would indicate that something in your old profile has got corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first delete your firefox **user profile** and try again , using following command you can delete firefox user profile:

> rm -rf ~/.mozilla/firefox/.default

Where  is the name of your profile that firefox generates random.

Comment: exactly i fixed my firefox problem like this